# ByRef argument type mismatch error in new module

Tags: excel, vba

The following code works fine when its in a project all by itself, but as soon as I put it in the project containing all my code I get a "`ByRef argument type mismatch error`". I don't get why this is happening.

It's breaking on the following row: `If Left(midText, 2) = "|-" Then`

I don't reference midText in any other code within my project.

```
Function ColumnHelper(midText As String, inBold As Boolean, _
                        inColor As Integer, inStrikeThru As Boolean)
    Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
    Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    If Selection.Count > 1 Then
    'this performs a "softcenter"
        Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
    Else
        Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End If

    Dim dashCount As Integer
    Dim tempText As String
    If Left(midText, 2) = "|-" Then
        On Error Resume Next 'count dashes before space
        For i = 2 To Len(midText) - 1
            If Mid(midText, i, 1) = "-" Then
                dashCount = dashCount + 1
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        tempText = Mid(midText, dashCount + 3, Len(midText) _
                                      - (2 * (dashCount + 2)))
        If Err = 0 Then
            midText = tempText
        End If
    End If

    Dim selWidth As Integer 'Get the width of the selection
    For Each cell In Selection.Rows(1)
        selWidth = selWidth + cell.Width
    Next cell

    Dim dashes As String 'Create a string containing dashes
    dashes = "-"

    For i = 0 To CInt(selWidth / 6) - (0.9 * Len(midText)) - 5
        dashes = dashes + "-"
    Next i
    Dim dashLen As Integer
    dashLen = Len(dashes)

    Selection.Item(1).FormulaR1C1 = "|" + dashes + " " + midText + _
                " " + dashes + "|" 'Input text into cell
    With Selection.Item(1).Font
        .Name = "System"
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Size = 8
        .ColorIndex = inColor
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlNone
    End With
    With Selection.Item(1).Characters(Start:=Len(dashes) + 2, _
                                        Length:=Len(midText) + 2).Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        If inBold Then
            .FontStyle = "Bold"
        Else
            .FontStyle = "Regular"
        End If
        .Strikethrough = inStrikeThru
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: How are you calling the function? e.g. `ColumnHelper( ... )` Is the supplied `midText` argument string-valued?

Comment: What is the value of `midText` when the error occurs?  Also, IMO `On Error Resume Next` should be avoided if at all possible, and this is an example why. You probably intended to use it temporarily but you didn't turn error handling back on afterwards, so errors are ignored for the last half of your code.  Also I'd suggestion putting the line `Option Explicit` at the top of [every] module [always] to help prevent issues such as your undeclared variables.

Comment: FWIW You change its value in the function so explicitly pass ByRef i.e. ByRef midText As String...

Comment: @arbie - I tidied up the formatting of your code so it's more legible, but there is a lot of irrelevant stuff in there. Please see **how to create a [mcve]** and [edit] your question to include *only* the minimal amount of code required to reproduce the problem, and include *everything* required to reproduce it, including sample data.  More tips at "[ask]" and also see [help.on-topic].  When you do the [tour] you will earn your first badge.  Even more tips [**here**](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) from the site's top user.

Comment: @LeeMac i'm calling with the following code:

Sub Blue_Columnar()
    
    Dim cellContents As Variant
    Dim vOldSelection As Range
    Set vOldSelection = Selection
    For Each area In Selection.Areas
        area.Select
        cellContents = Selection.Item(1)
        ColumnHelper Format(cellContents), True, 5, False
    Next area
    
    vOldSelection.Select
    Exit Sub

Answer (score 0):

An example call would help but here are some observations:

1) This is a sub not a function. It does things but doesn't return anything. Consider whether you actually need to return anything (in which case would be a function and you need an assignment and the signature should indicate the return type).

2) It modifies the value of `midText` so you could pass `ByRef` explicitly.

3) You have undeclared variables (e.g. `i, Cell)` which means you aren't using `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, which you should.

4) You have an unclosed `On Error Resume Next` masking any potential errors.

5) Use meaningful variable names and non ambiguous e.g. don't use `Cell` as a variable name.

6) Use `Long` not `Integer` to reduce potential risk of overflow.

7) You can make use of more effient typed functions e.g. `Mid$`

8) You don't do anything with `dashLen` . It can be removed potentially.

9) Can you break this into smaller subs/functions handling individual tasks?

Some of those suggestions:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()

    ColumnHelper "HELLO", True, 2, True

End Sub

Public Sub ColumnHelper(ByRef midText As String, ByVal inBold As Boolean, ByVal inColor As Long, ByVal inStrikeThru As Boolean)
    Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
    Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    If Selection.Count > 1 Then
        Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
    Else
        Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End If

    Dim dashCount As Long, tempText As String, i As Long
    If Left$(midText, 2) = "|-" Then

        For i = 2 To Len(midText) - 1
            If Mid$(midText, i, 1) = "-" Then
                dashCount = dashCount + 1
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        tempText = Mid$(midText, dashCount + 3, Len(midText) - (2 * (dashCount + 2)))
        If Err = 0 Then
            midText = tempText
        End If
    End If

    Dim selWidth As Long, iCell As Range
    For Each iCell In Selection.Rows(1)
        selWidth = selWidth + iCell.Width
    Next iCell

    Dim dashes As String
    dashes = "-"
    For i = 0 To CInt(selWidth / 6) - (0.9 * Len(midText)) - 5
        dashes = dashes + "-"
    Next i

    Dim dashLen As Long
    dashLen = Len(dashes)

    Selection.Item(1).FormulaR1C1 = "|" + dashes + " " + midText + _
                                    " " + dashes + "|"
    With Selection.Item(1).Font
        .Name = "System"
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Size = 8
        .ColorIndex = inColor
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlNone
    End With
    With Selection.Item(1).Characters(Start:=Len(dashes) + 2, Length:=Len(midText) + 2).Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        If inBold Then
            .FontStyle = "Bold"
        Else
            .FontStyle = "Regular"
        End If
        .Strikethrough = inStrikeThru
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: i am calling with the following code:

Sub Blue_Columnar()
    
    Dim cellContents As Variant
    Dim vOldSelection As Range
    Set vOldSelection = Selection
    For Each area In Selection.Areas
        area.Select
        cellContents = Selection.Item(1)
        ColumnHelper Format(cellContents), True, 5, False
    Next area
    
    vOldSelection.Select
    Exit Sub

Comment: Did you try with my amendments?

Comment: Yea i did i get this error now: "type declaration character does not match declared data type"

It works fine when I do it in a completely separate project, but as soon I put that code in my ongoing project it breaks with that mentioned error code

Comment: on which line is error? I cannot reproduce as runs fine including with your code. Just had to add  Dim area As Range

Comment: Its on the same line as before... "If Left$(midText, 2) = "|-" Then"

I can provide the other code if you think that would be helpful?

Comment: It might be. But you say the error is in this bit of code. midText is declared as string so shouldn't be a problem. I am wondering if you have a glitchy project now. Is it possible to recreate the project?

Comment: Yea the error shows up in this code, but only when its added to the project. For Example when I run it in the "VBAProject (Book 1)" its fine. But as soon as I add it the project i've created "VBAProject (Arbie)", i get those errors

Comment: Maybe use a new project then if possible? I have made the main suggestions I can.

Comment: I ended up deleting this pieces out completely and it seems to work just fine now

` If Left$(midText, 2) = "|-" Then

        For i = 2 To Len(midText) - 1
            If Mid$(midText, i, 1) = "-" Then
                dashCount = dashCount + 1
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        tempText = Mid$(midText, dashCount + 3, Len(midText) - (2 * (dashCount + 2)))
        If Err = 0 Then
            midText = tempText
        End If
    End If`